# How to fetch all gas stations inside a polygon using Google Places API

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, geocoding

[image]

I need to show each and every gas station which is located within a certain polygon. We are using Google Places API. Google has a Javascript function to search places within bounds, but it only gives 20 results (max 60 by using pagination). But I want to capture each and every result. So it might be that I have to divide the area into boxes, or something like that. Please advise.

Comment: Say you divide your polygon in 2 and still get 60 results for one or both, that means there are still *probably* more results than that... So I don't see this as a viable solution unless your script shows a fixed area and you know in advance there are more than 60 results. In that case then yes, break it into smaller parts and make multiple requests. Otherwise you should maybe think about showing the most relevant results instead of **all**, unless your goal is to dump all the data from Google, which I believe is against their TOS...